# Set Env variables based on grunt task

Tags: web-applications, ember.js, gruntjs

I have a webapp (emberjs) that I need to set env variables based on grunt task. So when I run `grunt server` it would choose `development`, and url will be set to `localhost:5000`. But when i do `grunt build`, it would choose `production` and url will be set to `production.com`.

The main issue for me is, how to read those variables from ember. Or how to make grunt look for a variable and change it based on the task

Is it possible to do something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much googling and no good examples, here's what I did.

Assuming you're using yeoman with scaffolding by `yo ember` generator and using `grunt build` to build the dist.

Yo ember-generator v0.8 uses grunt-replace. Upgrade to that version. In short, I'm using grunt-replace to add global vars to index.html. Here's how.

Add this script tag to app/index.html before the combined-scripts.js block:

```
#app/index.html
<script>
  /*
    simplify grunt-replace strategy by placing env vars here.
  */
  window.MYCOMPANYCOM_ENV = {
    env: '@@env',
    apiHost: '@@apiHost'
  };
</script>

/* ADD THE ABOVE BEFORE THIS SECTION */
<!-- build:js(.tmp) scripts/main.js -->
<script src="scripts/combined-scripts.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

And change the replace config in Gruntfile.js to this:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  var appConfig = grunt.file.readJSON('app_config.json');

replace: {
  app: {
    options: {
      patterns: [
        {
          json: appConfig['app']
        }
      ]
    },
    files: [
      {src: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html', dest: '.tmp/index.html'}
    ]
  },
  dist: {
    options: {
      patterns: [
        {
          json: appConfig['dist']
        }
      ]
    },
    files: [
      {src: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/index.html', dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/index.html'}
    ]
  }
}
```

Create a new file at ./app_config.json

```
{
  "app": {
    "env": "development",
    "apiHost": "http://localhost:8080"
    },
  "dist": {
    "env": "dist",
    "apiHost": "/"
    }
}
```

Now your app scripts have access to a global vars defined in app_config.json.

I won't go into more detail but this works fine in development. For `grunt build`, I moved the `replace:dist` step to the end of the build steps, and replaced the @@ember variable in index.html with a path to the bower component.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. Using [`grunt-env`](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-env) to specify your environment in combination with something like [`grunt-usemin`](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-usemin) to expose your environment variables to your application code.

According to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839458/how-do-i-set-an-env-variable-in-emberjs) you need to ensure that your environment variables are loaded prior to Ember.js.

Comment: I have a working ENV variables set before emberjs, and grunt-env seems great to define variables there. But how can match grunt-env variables to be set in a place of my choice. Is there a way like find and replace? How can I put the variables in a specific place before building or running server?

Comment: See the answers in [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401998/have-grunt-generate-index-html-for-different-setups). As per my answer, I've suggested you use something like [`grunt-usemin`](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-usemin) to expose your environment variables to your app, but if you check out the [thread I linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401998/have-grunt-generate-index-html-for-different-setups) you can see there are more ways to skin this cat.